# Try/except when using Python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, try-except

Doing some API testing and trying to create a function that given an inputted URL it will return the json response, however if a HTTP error is the response an error message will be returned.

I was using urllib2 before, but now trying to use requests instead. However it looks like my except block is never executed, regardless of the error.

```
testURL = 'http://httpbin.org/status/404'


def return_json(URL):
    try:
        response = requests.get(URL)
        json_obj = response.json()
        return json_obj
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        return "Error: " + str(e)
```

The result I get from running the above...

```
<Response [404]>
```

Comment: What exactly do you consider a HTTP error? There's status codes, but not everything other than `200` necessarily means there's an error of some sort. As you noticed, the `request` library considers those just another aspect of a HTTP response and doesn't raise an exception. So you'd need to be a bit more specific about what constitutes an "error" for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I think for my case anything other than 200 should be considered an error.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you want the response to raise an exception for a non-200 status code use `response.raise_for_status()`. Your code would then look like:

```
testURL = 'http://httpbin.org/status/404'


def return_json(URL):
    response = requests.get(testURL)

    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        # Whoops it wasn't a 200
        return "Error: " + str(e)

    # Must have been a 200 status code
    json_obj = response.json()
    return json_obj
```

You can tell that this is clearly simpler than the other solutions here and doesn't require you to check the status code manually. You would also just catch an `HTTPError` since that is what `raise_for_status` will raise. Catching `RequestsException` is a poor idea. That will catch things like `ConnectionError`s or `TimeoutError`s, etc. None of those mean the same thing as what you're trying to catch.

Answer (score 19):

**Note**: You should rather go with `response.raise_for_status()` as described in [Ian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24531618/1599111) above (*he's one of the maintainers of the `requests` module*).

---

How you handle this all depends on what you consider an HTTP error. There's status codes, but not everything other than `200` necessarily means there's an error of some sort.

As you noticed, the request library considers those just another aspect of a HTTP response and doesn't raise an exception. HTTP status `302` for example means `Found`, but the response doesn't contain a response body but a `Location` header instead that you'd need to follow to get to the resource you actually wanted.

So you'll want to look at [`response.status_code`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes), and do your handling of that, while catching actual **protocol errors** with a `try..except`. When catching those you should actually catch `requests.exceptions.RequestException`, because this is the [base class for all other exceptions](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py) the `requests` module raises.

So here's an example that demonstrates all three cases:

- Sucessfull `200 OK` response
- Sucessful request and response, but status other than `200`
- Protocol error (invalid schema)

```
import requests

test_urls = ['http://httpbin.org/user-agent',
             'http://httpbin.org/status/404',
             'http://httpbin.org/status/500',
             'httpx://invalid/url']


def return_json(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)

        # Consider any status other than 2xx an error
        if not response.status_code // 100 == 2:
            return "Error: Unexpected response {}".format(response)

        json_obj = response.json()
        return json_obj
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # A serious problem happened, like an SSLError or InvalidURL
        return "Error: {}".format(e)


for url in test_urls:
    print "Fetching URL '{}'".format(url)
    print return_json(url)
    print
```

Output:

```
Fetching URL 'http://httpbin.org/user-agent'
{u'user-agent': u'python-requests/2.1.0 CPython/2.7.1 Darwin/11.4.2'}

Fetching URL 'http://httpbin.org/status/404'
Error: Unexpected response <Response [404]>

Fetching URL 'http://httpbin.org/status/500'
Error: Unexpected response <Response [500]>

Fetching URL 'httpx://invalid/url'
Error: No connection adapters were found for 'httpx://invalid/url'
```

There could also be an exception raised by `response.json()` if you get a sucessfull response, but it simply isn't JSON - so you might want to account for that as well.

---

**Note**: The `if not response.status_code // 100 == 2` bit works like this:
The `//` operator does a so called [floor division](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv), so it rounds down to the next integer (this is the default behavior for the `/` in Python 2.x, but not Python 3.x, which changed `/` to do floating point division). So `status // 100 == 2` holds true for all `2xx` codes.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks Lukas. I edited it a little to account for all 2xx codes... if not str(response.status_code)[0] == 2

Comment: Good point also about the non-JSON successful response. I will look into that.

Comment: @obrienmorgan the `int(response.status_code / 100) == 2` already accounts for `2xx` ;-) On Python 2.x the division `/` operator does floor division (round down to the next integer), so `status / 100 == 2` is true for all `2xx` codes. On Python 3.x the division has been changed to floating point division, that's why the `int(...)` is needed to make it work for Python 2.x as well as 3.x.

Comment: Ahh okay, there's my inexperience shining through! Thanks a million for all your help Lukas, this works perfectly.

Comment: @obrienmorgan actually the clean way to do floor division in Python 2.x as well as 3.x is to use the `//` operator - updated my answer and explained that bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `response.status_code` value.  If it's not `200`, then you can consider it to be an error condition and throw your own exception.

Comment: Whups. You're right, @PadraicCunningham.  Thanks, fixing it now.

Comment: Thanks guys, this works. Added an if statement to check the response. But this abandons the use of Try/Except.